# SQL query logic to get Ids which have IsActive false for all the possible hierarchies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

Final result should not include id 24 as this id have active mapping with a company hierarchy: 1176->1781->1787 And 1787 is active in second table.
The query I tried is not able to get the desired result.

Sample data:

```
Table 1 #tempCTE_CompMCompDir: 

Id  CompanyId   ChildId
24  1776        1781
24  1776        1782
25  1777        1783
24  1781        1786
24  1781        1787

Table 2 #tempContComM:
CompanyId   ContactId   IsActive
1787            2903    1
1783            2903    0
1778            2903    0
1786            2903    0
```

Input:

1. Table 1 have hierarchical data Companies and children.
2. Table 2 have leaf level companies with IsActive true or false.

Output:

- Fetch all the Ids from Table 1

If Company Id or Child Id from table 1 is mapped to Company Id of table 2 via hierarchy AND IsActive for this mapping is false in all the cases.

Output for sample data should be:

```
Id
25
```

My query with wrong output is:

```
SELECT CTE_CompMCompDir.Id
    FROM #tempCTE_CompMCompDir  CTE_CompMCompDir
    JOIN #tempContComM          tempContComM
        ON   ( CTE_CompMCompDir.CompanyId  = tempContComM.CompanyId 
                    AND tempContComM.IsActive = 0)
            OR ( CTE_CompMCompDir.ChildId     = tempContComM.CompanyId
                    AND tempContComM.IsActive = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question need more information.  Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would help.  A SQL/DB fiddle of some type would help.  And a clear explanation.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2029983)

Comment: Is it fine now? Please let me know if more explanation required.

Comment: @Rob I have edited the question and it's header as suggested. Please let me know if it needs more from my side. Thank you for bringing this aspect.

Comment: @Rob I may have unintentionally used wrong question header. But one can observe from the question. I have provided sample data with schema as suggested. I have provided brief input and required output as suggested. Also I have provided a query which I tried and I just need help in logic of this query I wrote at my own. So my intention is not for code writing services from here. I need a direction to write a logic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution if you are only looking for all child rows entries in the second table which have all false Isactive values

<kbd>[live demo link](https://rextester.com/UBPHJ90190)</kbd>

```
create table tempCTE_CompMCompDir (Id  int, CompanyId int,   ChildId int)

insert into tempCTE_CompMCompDir
values
(24,  1776,  1781),
(24,  1776,  1782),
(25,  1777,  1783),
(24,  1781,  1786),
(24,  1781,  1787);


create table tempContComM(CompanyId  int,  ContactId  int, IsActive bit);

insert into tempContComM 
values
(1787  ,2903 , 1),
(1783  ,2903 , 0),
(1778  ,2903 , 0),
(1786  ,2903 , 0);

select t.* from tempCTE_CompMCompDir t join (
    select 
    id,value=max(case when ISNULL(Isactive,-1)=0 then 0 else 1 end)
    from tempCTE_CompMCompDir l 
        left join tempContComM r
            on l.companyid=r.companyid or l.childid=r.companyid
    group by id 
    ) t2 
        on t.id=t2.id and t2.value=0
```

Couple of notes:

1. I treated missing mapping values as neither false or true
2. you can tweak max (case..) to change your rules and criterias

Answer (score 1):

This query discards all the #tempCTE_CompMCompDir.Id where the CompanyId or the ChildId matches a raw where IsActive = 1 into the second table; which is my understanding of what you are trying to achieve

```
select T1.Id
from #tempCTE_CompMCompDir T1
inner join #tempContComM T2
on T1.CompanyId = T2.CompanyId or T1.ChildId = T2.CompanyId
group by T1.Id
having max(cast(IsActive as int)) = 0
```